How to visualize the dependency property of a user control in design
I have a couple of UserControls which I extend with Dependency Properties:
public static DependencyProperty CustomBrushProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register(
      nameof(CustomBrush),
      typeof(Brush),
      typeof(CustomComboBox),
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Application.Current.Resources["PrimarySolidColorBrush"])); // Specified in another Styles.xaml file

public Brush CustomBrush
{
  get
  {
      return GetValue(CustomBrushProperty) as Brush;
  }
  set
  {
      SetValue(CustomBrushProperty, value);
  }
}

BorderBrush="{Binding CustomBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:CustomUserControl}}}"

I can see that the brush is correctly rendered in the running app, but the default value (Transparent?) seems to be rendered in the design. Is there a way to visualize how the Brush is rendered in the design as defined in the Dictionary?

Binding to "properties" has no effect until the DataContext is set. On the other hand, if you use (Static) Resources to style, it should show up at design time. Using a property in this case, implies objects with different colors ... and you have no "object" per se at  design time other than what the designer can "mock" with just a default constructor. I mean, you can make "design" changes to the XAML, while the app is running ... sometimes that's the ideal time to make certain changes. i.e. the "live" visual tree.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-hot-reload?view=vs-2022
